# GIS data import

Tags: workflow, import, file-format

I used to work in the mapping industry and I'm interested in seeing what capabilities Blender has in importing GIS based data sets and blending them together.

Ideally I would like to be able to import .shp, .jpg, Collada, .NITF, and .tif files and merge them to create a terrain using real world topology/hydrology/etc.

I just recently found a Blender plug in off of Github called BlenderGIS which provides .shp functionality. I would love to be able to import LIDAR or some other topology maps and drape a satellite/airplane image over the lines/points to make a 3D map.

Let me know if you know of any currently implemented solutions. I'm really excited about the prospect of this.

Comment: Resources for this question should be incorporated to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Answer (score 5):

GIS in Blender is currently represented by 2 addons:

1) https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS (Shapefile and georeferenced raster files)

2) https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo (OpenStreetMap, SRTM, GPX).

Also read [here](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-geo/wiki/Georeferenced-Blender-Scene) how georeferencing can be introduced to Blender.

Comment: Great! I'll look into those.
I have BlenderGIS and am working on getting it added to Blender. There are some issues with it having to be encoded with UTF-8 and the scripts are being imported at all at the moment.